# run jar using bat file in server

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, cmd

I have a application hosted in server. I have a bat file which will run a .jar file. The jar is running when i double click on bat/jar. But when a integrated it in my application and tried to run the jar, it is not executing.

Here is the code for running bat file :

```
<%
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c D:\\Create_Confluence.bat");
%>
```

This code runs, because when we tried creating a folder the cmd runs & creates the folder.

Here is the code inside bat file for running the .jar:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\java" -jar D:\confluence.jar "D:\\Eclipse\\Fourprojects\\Excel\\Space.xls" 
pause
```

But the jar file is not getting executed.

Can somebody help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide working directory as like below .

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c Create_Confluence.bat", null,"D:\\");
```

Check this method here in this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime())

```
public Process exec(String command,
                    String[] envp,
                    File dir)
             throws IOException
```

***Parameters:**

> command - a specified system command.
>
> envp - array of strings, each element of which has environment
>   variable settings in the format name=value, or null if the subprocess
>   should inherit the environment of the current process.
>
> dir - the working directory of the subprocess, or null if the
>   subprocess should inherit the working directory of the current
>   process.*